# Robust watermarking in change format

Tags: signal-analysis

I watermarked a picture in sound .WAV file, when today i find this sound file after 3 years  try to extract picture embed in sound but i understand format of this chang to .mp3 and thus I can't extract completely picture of watermarked .My question about , find a watermarking algorithm that is resistant to any kind of compression?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Are you trying to extract a watermark after the WAV file was compressed to MP3? Or are you trying to find a watermarking algorithm that is resistant to this kind of compression?

Comment: Are you perhaps referring to [Steganography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Watermarking and steganography are very related to each other. While steganography is interested in capacity and invisibility, watermarking is to provide robustness to protect hidden data against any attacking methods like *compressing, cropping, noise addition* etc. LSB Coding, Phase Coding, Spread Spectrum, Echo Hiding are basic methods you should search about.

I suggest you to read these articles for the basics:

1. [Audio Watermarking Techniques, Hyoung Joong Kim](http://www.ibrarian.net/navon/paper/Audio_Watermarking_Techniques.pdf?paperid=10290199)
2. [Robust and Reliable Audio Watermarking Based on Dynamic Phase Coding and Error Control Coding](http://www.eurasip.org/Proceedings/Eusipco/Eusipco2015/papers/1570104339.pdf)

First article is very helpful to start. I advice you to try ***Spread Spectrum*** method, it was very robust against mp3 compression as I have coded myself.  I had answered my own question [*here*](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/35540/spread-spectrum-audio-steganography) trying to explain steps of [*Direct Sequence Spread Spectrum Method*](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/35540/spread-spectrum-audio-steganography) to embed data inside audio files. It may also help you.